# TypeError: this.form.submit is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I created a form, with a `select` dropdown menu that submits the form on submit in javascript/html...

here it is:

```
 <form action="/adminFilter" method="POST">
    <select name="filter" id="selectBox" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="">FILTER</option>
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="ACTIVE">Registered</option>
    <option value="WAITLIST">Waitlisted</option>
    <option value="CANCELLED">Cancelled</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

however, when I change one of the values, it actually presents me with this error in the web console.

```
TypeError: this.form.submit is not a function. (In 'this.form.submit()', 'this.form.submit' is an instance of RadioNodeList)
```

why is this happening, how do I fix this? I basically want to submit the form when someone changes the value of the select dropdown. Is this possible this way?

edited:

```
<script>
    // write the function
    function submitForm() {
        document.querySelector("#my-form").submit();
    }
    
 </script>
    

   
<form action="/adminFilter" method="POST" id="my-form">
    <select name="filter" id="selectBox" onchange="submitForm();">       
         <option value="">FILTER</option>
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="ACTIVE">Registered</option>
    <option value="WAITLIST">Waitlisted</option>
    <option value="CANCELLED">Cancelled</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector("#my-form").submit')
```

Comment: Give your form a name like `name="myform" and then on your select element `onchange=document.myform.submit()"

Comment: What do you mean by "change one of the values"? It works for me how you have it.

Comment: @Mike thats strange. When I select another option, it gives that error

Comment: @Gianluca Try creating a minimal example. I'm assuming you have some other JS that is causing some unwanted side effects.

Comment: No errors here: https://jsfiddle.net/80pfc72u/

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `form` an `id`, and whenever the value of the `select` changes, submit the form with the id you gave. Like:

```html
<script>
// write the function
function submitForm() {
    document.querySelector("#my-form").submit();
}

<script/>

<form action="/adminFilter" method="POST" id="my-form">
<select name="filter" id="selectBox" onchange="submitForm();">
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I got this: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('#my-form').submit')`

Comment: write a function for it, I've edited the answer, take a look

Comment: I see what you did, but I got the same error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector("#my-form").submit')`. I've edited my q to show what I did

Comment: I just did, plz see

Comment: sorry just saw it, it was not updating. I pasted your edited code, and everything worked just fine. Do you have any other piece of code that might affect this?

Comment: just the backend code, wouldn't be anything else

Comment: you can see the edited code working all right in this replit example: https://replit.com/@admin90873/VibrantCalmZip#index.html

Answer (score 0):

Give your form a name so that it could directly be queried from the document object.

```
<form action="/adminFilter" method="POST">
    <select name="filter" id="selectBox" onchange="onchange="this.parentNode.submit()">
    <option value="">FILTER</option>
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="ACTIVE">Registered</option>
    <option value="WAITLIST">Waitlisted</option>
    <option value="CANCELLED">Cancelled</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

EDIT:

You can call a function onchange so that document object is accessible.

```
<form action="/adminFilter" method="POST" name="myform">
    <select name="filter" id="selectBox" onchange="doSubmit()">
    <option value="">FILTER</option>
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="ACTIVE">Registered</option>
    <option value="WAITLIST">Waitlisted</option>
    <option value="CANCELLED">Cancelled</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and in JS

```
function doSubmit() {
  console.log(document.myform);
  document.myform.submit();
}
```

Comment: I like this approach as well, but I got this: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.myform.submit')`

Comment: got this error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.myform.submit')`. not sure why this is happening :(

Comment: Okay.. I updated my original answer. Hopefully that should work... For me all these 3 approached worked fine. Are you sure there is no typo?

Comment: still didn't work unfortunately, but thank you for the help! Something is weird in my code, I have to debug